# Why is public key cryptography used in sites like Google, Facebook (what is the need to encode data in these sites)?

Tags: cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption

The RSA algorithm is used for encryption (plain text to cipher text) and decryption (cipher text to plain text) of data. What is the need for using public keys in these sites; why is data encrypted as everything is viewed by everyone?

Why do we need to use public key cryptography in Google; how does it provide security?

Answer (score 5):

> What is the need for using public keys in these sites?

It is required to set up a shared secret (a big random number) that is used for further symmetric crypto. Public-private key crypto allows one to share a secret message (symmetric key material) *even when each and every message is monitored and eavesdropped.* See [Hot does SSL works?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/20803/2553) for more info.

The problem with public-private key crypto is that it is dead slow, whereas symmetric crypto is dead fast. The benefit is that public-private key crypto uses two keys for encryption and decryption and this is what allows to securely share a secret through the insecure channel, whereas symmetric crypto uses a shared key for both operations and you need both parties to have the same shared key.

> Why is data is encrypted as everything is viewed by everyone?

When data is encrypted all that an observer can see is pure random noise. An observer *cannot understand anything* from the encrypted communication. Unless storing encrypted communication, like NSA does, and later asking Google and other companies for their private key. In this way they can decrypt old communication.

> Why do we need to use public key cryptography in Google; how does it provide security?

Many agencies would like to know what people search for: "how to make a bomb", political disputes, etc. Advertisers would like to know what people interested in so that they can bring relevant ads. If something is provided to you for free, you are the product. You sell your information (your interests) and when this is done on a global scale suddenly huge money become involved.

Public-private key crypto in this sense provides privacy. Only you and the server can understand the traffic, but no one else: no intermediate hubs, your ISP or government body.

Before Facebook switched to SSL-by-default, all traffic was indeed plain text. This made it possible to build a graph of connections on a truly global scale. The rational I guess was to *possibly* aid anti-terrorist forces to catch the bad guys. From the other side all population's activities were tracked. See [PRISM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRISM_(surveillance_program)) for more info.